# Why is my DIVIDE() measure returning 1? or, Why is my numerator and denominator equal to each other?

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
DIVIDE(
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('fSampleResultsOilWater'),
        FILTER(
            'fSampleResultsOilWater',
            'fSampleResultsOilWater'[Severity]="Abnormal"||'fSampleResultsOilWater'[Severity]="Severe"
        ),
        FILTER(
            dDates,
            dDates[Q Year]="4Q2023"
        )
    ),
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('fSampleResultsOilWater'),
        ALL('fSampleResultsOilWater'),
        FILTER(
            'fSampleResultsOilWater',
            'fSampleResultsOilWater'[Severity]="Abnormal"||'fSampleResultsOilWater'[Severity]="Severe"
        ),
        FILTER(
            dDates,
            dDates[Q Year]="4Q2023"
        )
    )
)
```

I thought I was creating a smaller subset/value in the numerator by allowing the visual/slicer to filter the dataset on top while...

maintaining a larger subset in the denominator by removing the original context filter with ALL().

So, shouldn't the only difference between the numerator and denominator be that the numerator has one extra set of filters?

Thus, resulting in a fraction?

Answer (score 0):

See if it helps

```html
DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'fSampleResultsOilWater' ),
        'fSampleResultsOilWater'[Severity] IN { "Abnormal", "Severe" },
        dDates[Q Year] = "4Q2023"
    ),
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'fSampleResultsOilWater' ),
        'fSampleResultsOilWater'[Severity] IN { "Abnormal", "Severe" },
        REMOVEFILTERS ( fSampleResultsOilWater ),
        dDates[Q Year] = "4Q2023"
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to IN and REMOVEFILTERS. Always wondered about IN when reading others' code. I will try this when I'm back at work tomorrow.

That said, any idea why mine is returning 1?